# Delete unique queue job if exists Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a job that updates permissions.

Let's assume that in the frontend 'admin' modifies permissions twice (makes a mistake or something). - This creates 2 jobs.

The first job adds the role **manager**. |
The second job removes the role **manager**.

If for some reason the first job fails, the second job will be processed first and the 'user' will still have the **manager** role.

How should I solve this? I was thinking maybe I could delete all jobs with that specific 'user_id' before adding job to queue.

Comment: It has happened because PHP doesn't support asynchronous jobs. you must use an event\listener after your first job to send feedback to your next job.

Comment: Could you make the job `atomic`? Attempt to perform the operation and if any part if it fails, revert everything. That would keep your logic encapsulated and prevent you having to do error checking elsewhere, or passing messages around your system.

Comment: Since the permission editing takes time, I use queue workers. So if 'admin' modifies something, I notify immediately that the action was successful.